# Package APK in Visual Studio 2012 Using Mono For Android 4.2.7 Error

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk

I can't make an App Works in a real device using Mono for Android 4.2.7

Im using an Xperia X10a with Android 2.3.3

When I tried to open it in a real device it close; "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Im am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, in Project -> Properties; Configuration "Release", Use Shared Runtime (no).

Please help me, thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for your time. How can I see that?

Comment: Is it necesary to add an AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Mono for Android will generate an AndroidManifest.xml file for you. If you need to add permissions then you can add these through the project properties under the 'Android Manifest' tab. To view the logcat you can simply click on the (i) button next to the device selection combo box on the Mono for Android toolbar in Visual Studio  like in this image http://snag.gy/JjSZR.jpg

Comment: Thanks you a lot; here is the logcat: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=460800DC113FA2F7!31526&authkey=!AAWd0-uzROhH_NI

Comment: Is the application that is crashing called com.gyjgames.coloreater? Looks like there is an error in your OnCreate override for Activity1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you install it, you must create a serial key and then publish it.
for More:[Xamarin Documents](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/)